# Saving file stream data run time

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file

My File.txt contains

```
123456781
123456781
```

My NewFile should contain

```
123456782
123456782
```

Step1:  Copying the contents from old to new file

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\File.txt");
using (Stream file = File.Create("NewFile.txt"))
{
    CopyStream(reader.BaseStream, file);
}


private void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
     byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
     int len;
     while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
     {
         output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
     }
}
```

Step2: Having an issue here.

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("NewFile.txt");
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
   string currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
   //Logic to increment the number is written

    //Now saving the change to the file...

     if (reader!=null && reader.ReadLine() != null)
     {
        //contents is the file content with the changed numbers
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contents);
        MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        File.AppendAllText("New.txt", contents); //Here is the issue
     }

}
```

I am not ablel to save it. How can i save it runtime, if i specify new file name, i don't get both lines getting saved.

```
File.AppendAllText("New2.txt", contents);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that inside the `while` loop, your code does two times `reader.ReadLine()` in succession.

The first time your code reads a line from "NewFile.txt" into the variable **currentLine**:

```
string currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
```

and then right after that it reads the next line from the reader:

```
if (reader!=null && reader.ReadLine() != null)
```

but it does not keep this second line read from the file anywhere.

That means, your `while` loop discards every second line from "NewFile.txt". (If "NewFile.txt" would only contain one line, nothing would happen since the if-condition would never be satisfied.)

Also note that testing for `reader != null` is redundant here. If *reader* would be *null*, your code would already throw an exception at `while (!reader.EndOfStream)`.

Change your code inside the `while` loop to something like:

```
string currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentLine))
{
   //Logic to increment the number is written

   //Now saving the change to the file...

    string contents = ... get/create contents string from somewhere ...

    //contents is the file content with the changed numbers
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contents);
    MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    File.AppendAllText("New.txt", contents); //Here is the issue
}
```

Note, that i used `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`. Depending on your needs and minimum required framework version, you might use `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()`, or just use `if (currentLine != null)`.

(Also, i don't know what the MemoryStream **myStream** is good for. However, since you had it in your example code, i also included it in my example code, although *myStream* does not fulfill any purpose here.)